# Why is a test statistic called a test statistic?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, terminology

I'm sure this is really basic -- but I want to understand the origins (etymology) of the term "test statistic".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is pretty straightforward, at least at one level. "Test" because it's the result of a test, "statistic" because it comes from a sample, not a population. (A mnemonic: Populations have Parameters; Samples have Statistics).

Or did you want something on the origin of the term "statistic"?

Comment: Actually I think you've answered it for me.

Answer (score 2):

The term [*statistic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic) has a particular meaning in stats.

For present purposes we could take it to be a real valued function of a set of observations. (For a given sample, that would give a number calculated from the sample.)

A *test statistic* is then a statistic that is used as the basis for a *hypothesis test*.